# Conditional CSS in GWT

Tags: css, gwt

I'm using GWT.

Is it possible with CSS to do the following if/else statement?

```
.unseen-activity div.unseen-label {
    display: inline;

    if using chrome { left: 510px; }
    else { left: 470px; }

    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or would it be better for my GWT Java code to check for browsers, and then add style accordingly?

Note - I'm not sure if it's possible in GWT to check the browser.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: you should ask why you need to change the css according to the browser instead. unless you did something very rare, it should not happen.

Comment: Chrome renders my CSS differently than Firefox, which is why I needed this conditional CSS. They use different renderers (Web Kit versus Gecko).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GWT's `CssResource` can do:

```
@if user.agent safari {
    .unseen-activity div.unseen-label {
        left: 510px;
    }
}
@else {
    .unseen-activity div.unseen-label {
        left: 470px;
    }
}

.unseen-activity div.unseen-label {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle#Conditional_CSS

Note: the `safari` user agent matches all webkits; if you need something else, use a static method as your `@if` test.

Comment: Wrt the [recent edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13404821/2) of this answer: the `@if`/`@else`, while not necessary, makes it more obvious what's going on here rather than relying the more implicit _override_.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is a pure style sheet language and has no options for decision making integrated. You will need to do it in java when using GWT, or using javascript.

Comment: Respectfully, I take back my Up-Vote since, as Thomas pointed out, it's possible to add decision-making logic to CSS.

Comment: that is not CSS. That is a file that needs to be pre-processed by the server side and converted into a valid css file.

Comment: My bad for saying it was plain old CSS.